# Strict stationarity of a process defined as the product of lags of another process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

Here is a problem that just occurred to me and that may be novel or interesting, at least I could find no trace on here. I have a short proof by contradiction in mind but it suffers from a limiting issue.

Assume $\{X_t\}$ is a discrete time stochastic process. Define the stochastic process $\{Y_t\}$  as $Y_t:=X_tX_{t-1}$.

**1. Question.** If $\{Y_t\}$ is strictly stationary, can we conclude that $\{X_t\}$ must be strictly stationary as well?

**2. Follow-on question.** How would the answer change if instead $Y_t:=X_tX_{t-1}X_{t-2}\cdots$?

Comment: Let $X_t$ alternate between zero and one deterministically.

Comment: Omg. Thanks a lot @spaceisdarkgreen.